# Infinite form submit with $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

i want to create a post form it'll get data from my url and post it to my database.
When i clicked the "Add" buton its working fine but when i try to add with $(document).ready function, I'm getting infinite loop. (My goal is submitting form every time i execute the file)
I've no knowlage about jquery and Im using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
document.forms["form1"].submit();
});
</script>
```

How can I get rid off infinite loop?

Comment: do your form has any id attribute

Comment: problem is every time page's loaded it's again submitted.. one solution might be is to post to a different php file and after you're done with processing data.. add redirection `header("Location: myOtherPage.php");` to code there to avoid infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try?

```
$(document).one("ready",function(){
  // submit form here
});
```

Comment: I've tried but getting loop again :/
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).one("ready",function(){
       $('#form1').submit();
    });
</script>

Comment: Check my answer bellow plz.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your form does not have action-attribute, hence it posts to itself. Add action attribute to the page you want to post to:

```
<form action="mypage.html"....
```

Comment: My php functions and my form is on the same page, so my form working like that: <form id="form1" method="POST"> (Because I want to do all the work in one page)

Comment: Then you shouldn't be suprised of the infinitive post-loop, whenever the page gets loaded, it posts to itself.

Comment: But my problem is, i executed the page one time, it posting infinite time.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use cookie to store first load information and check it before submitting form. Set the expire time as per your project requirement. Before using jQuery cookie, you have add cookie plugin after jQuery library.

*jQuery Cookie: [jQuery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (! $.cookie("cookieName")){
       document.forms["form1"].submit(); // do your stuff          
       $.cookie("cookieName", "firstSet", {"expires" : 7}); // set cookie now
    }

});
</script>
```

Hope will help!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
<form action="yourformname.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

If there is any file upload control, then use enctype in form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a flag can do the job.

```
var flag = true;
$(document).ready(function(){

   if(flag){
     // submit code here
     flag = false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside your form paste this line,

```
    <input type="hidden" name="ispost" value="0" id="ispost">
```

And in jQuery add this, your issue will be resolved

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       if($('#ispost').val() != 'submit')
       {
          $('#ispost').val('submit');
          $('#form1').submit();
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @putvande I have editted solution please view, his question was bit confusing to me at first read.

Comment: I'm guessing i could'nt explain my problem. I want to submit form on page load so $(document).ready function is important to me and I dont know anything about jquery but it's not worked for me :/

Comment: @user3057276 I have updated answer please follow the second selotion, do your form has any id?, the replace your form id like $('#paste_your_form_id_here').submit();

Comment: I'm guessing we're close. Could we use jquery .one function here?
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#form1').submit();
    });
</script>

Comment: @user3057276 I have edited solution this will resolve your issue. please try it